# Tatsu Parsing Performance

Tags: performance, tatsu

I've implemented a grammar in Tatsu for parsing a description of a quantum program *Quipper ASCII* ([link](https://github.com/eddieschoute/quippy/tree/f6488617c00f169258e9a4ea192bdf67dd80e72a)). The parser works but is slow for the files I'm looking at (about 10kB-1MB size, see the `resources` directory). It takes approximately 10-30 seconds to parse some files. The grammar is very straightforward and it should be possible to parse these files fairly quickly. One thing I've tried is adding cuts wherever possible to make sure there is no unneeded backtracking. The grammar is specified as

```
@@grammar :: Quipper
@@whitespace :: /[^\S\n]*/

# The root of any program
start::BCircuit = circuit:circuit subroutines:{subroutine} {newline} $ ;

# A sequence of gates
circuit::Circuit =
    "Inputs:" ~ inputs:arity
    gatelist:{gate newline}
    "Outputs: "outputs:arity
    ;

# "Function" definitions
subroutine::Subroutine =
    newline
    "Subroutine:" ~ name:string newline
    "Shape:" shape:string newline
    "Controllable:" controllable:("yes"|"no"|"classically") newline
    circuit:circuit
    ;

# Wires and their types.
arity = @:",".{type_assignment}+ newline ;
type_assignment::TypeAssignment = number:int ":" type:("Qbit"|"Cbit") ;

# Gate control
control_app = [controlled:controlled] [no_control:no_control];
controlled::Controlled = "with controls=[" ~ controls:",".{int}+ "]" ;
no_control::NoControl = "with nocontrol" ;

# All gates
gate
    =
    | qgate
    | qrot
    | gphase
    | cnot
    | cgate
    | cswap
    | qprep
    | qunprep
    | qinit
    | cinit
    | cterm
    | qmeas
    | qdiscard
    | cdiscard
    | dterm
    | subroutine_call
    | comment
    ;

# Gate definitions
qgate::QGate::Gate = "QGate[" ~ name:string "]" inverse:["*"] "(" qubit:int ")" > control_app;
qrot::QRot::Gate = "QRot[" ~ string "," double "](" int ")" ;
gphase::GPhase::Gate = "Gphase() with t=" ~ timestep:double >control_app "with anchors=[" ~ wires:",".{wire} "]" ;
cnot::CNo::Gate  = "CNot(" ~ wire:wire ")" >control_app ;
cgate::CGat::Gate  = "CGate[" ~ name:string "]" inverse:["*"] "(" wires:",".{wire} ")" no_control;
cswap::CSwap::Gate = "CSwap(" ~ wire1:wire "," wire2:wire ")" >control_app ;
qprep::QPrep::Gate = "QPrep(" ~ wire:wire ")" no_control ;
qunprep::QUnprep::Gate = "QUnprep(" ~ wire:wire ")" no_control ;
qinit::QInit::Gate = state:("QInit0" | "QInit1") ~ "(" wire:wire ")" no_control;
cinit::CInit::Gate = state:("CInit0" | "CInit1") ~ "(" wire:wire ")" no_control;
qterm::QTerm::Gate = state:("QTerm0" | "QTerm1") ~ "(" wire:wire ")" no_control;
cterm::CTerm::Gate = state:("CTerm0" | "CTerm1") ~ "(" wire:wire ")" no_control;
qmeas::QMeas::Gate = "QMeas(" ~ wire:wire ")" ;
qdiscard::QDiscard::Gate = "QDiscard(" ~ wire:wire ")" ;
cdiscard::CDiscard::Gate = "CDiscard(" ~ wire:wire ")" ;
dterm::DTerm::Gate = state:("DTerm0" | "Dterm1") ~ "(" wire:wire ")" ;
subroutine_call::SubCall::Gate = "Subroutine" ~ ["(x" repetitions:int ")"]
    "[" name:string ", shape" shape:string "]"
    inverse:["*"]
    "(" inputs:",".{int}+ ")"
    "-> (" outputs:",".{int}+ ")"
    >control_app ;
comment::Comment::Gate = "Comment[" ~ text:string "](" wires:",".{wire}+ ")" ;

# Reference to an input wire and a textual description
wire::Wire = qubit:int ":" text:string ;

# Literals
string = '"'@:String_literal'"';  # Don't include the quotes.
String_literal::str = /[^"]+/ ;
int::int = /([+|-])?\d+/ ;
double::float = /(-)?\d+\.\d+e(-)?\d+/ ;
newline = /\n/ ;
```

I've tried profiling the code to find bottlenecks in the performance, but time is spent all over the place. I generate a parser with `tatsu grammar.ebnf` and model with `tatsu -g`, which I then use in a test cases to parse input files. Performance results using standard `python` 3.6.4, sorted by `tottime`, for parsing all files in `resources/PF`:

```
Tue Feb 27 13:35:58 2018    parser_profiling

         4787639497 function calls (4611051402 primitive calls) in 3255.157 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time
   List reduced from 326 to 30 due to restriction <30>

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
144386670  129.008    0.000  491.328    0.000 /Users/eddie/dev/quippy/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tatsu/buffering.py:245(_eat_regex)
312540554   92.592    0.000  216.890    0.000 {built-in method builtins.isinstance}
15701720/80   88.741    0.000 3249.970   40.625 /Users/eddie/dev/quippy/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tatsu/contexts.py:561(_invoke_rule)
 34327680   87.957    0.000  370.060    0.000 /Users/eddie/dev/quippy/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tatsu/ast.py:14(__init__)
 57815550   76.052    0.000  380.881    0.000 /Users/eddie/dev/quippy/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tatsu/buffering.py:322(matchre)
 95427920   75.086    0.000  149.629    0.000 /Users/eddie/dev/quippy/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tatsu/buffering.py:208(goto)
 67455280   74.390    0.000  124.299    0.000 /Users/eddie/dev/quippy/.venv/bin/../lib/python3.6/abc.py:178(__instancecheck__)
 45115140   69.378    0.000  671.723    0.000 /Users/eddie/dev/quippy/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tatsu/buffering.py:260(next_token)
 57815550   67.317    0.000  143.516    0.000 /Users/eddie/dev/quippy/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tatsu/buffering.py:329(_scanre)
 32497610   63.583    0.000   69.483    0.000 /Users/eddie/dev/quippy/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tatsu/ast.py:115(__hasattribute__)
15701720/80   63.262    0.000 3249.976   40.625 /Users/eddie/dev/quippy/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tatsu/contexts.py:501(_call)
 18626000   61.979    0.000  454.538    0.000 /Users/eddie/dev/quippy/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tatsu/contexts.py:644(_try)
 68655360   57.334    0.000   57.334    0.000 /Users/eddie/dev/quippy/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tatsu/ast.py:103(__setattr__)
 57815550   54.505    0.000   54.505    0.000 {method 'match' of '_sre.SRE_Pattern' objects}
126339356   49.908    0.000   49.908    0.000 /Users/eddie/dev/quippy/.venv/bin/../lib/python3.6/_weakrefset.py:70(__contains__)
 72092420   48.541    0.000  170.810    0.000 /Users/eddie/dev/quippy/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tatsu/buffering.py:211(move)
33410950/4018330   47.143    0.000  334.748    0.000 /Users/eddie/dev/quippy/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tatsu/objectmodel.py:149(_adopt_children)
 48867260   46.582    0.000  724.214    0.000 /Users/eddie/dev/quippy/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tatsu/contexts.py:237(_next_token)
 37932280   44.424    0.000   91.042    0.000 /Users/eddie/dev/quippy/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tatsu/contexts.py:277(_add_cst_node)
 48128890   44.030    0.000   58.493    0.000 /Users/eddie/dev/quippy/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tatsu/buffering.py:256(eat_eol_comments)
 36470510   43.970    0.000  234.524    0.000 /Users/eddie/dev/quippy/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tatsu/ast.py:48(update)
 24351260   43.216    0.000  120.680    0.000 /Users/eddie/dev/quippy/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tatsu/ast.py:60(set)
 18626000   41.821    0.000  545.252    0.000 /Users/eddie/dev/quippy/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tatsu/contexts.py:666(_option)
 75390600   40.445    0.000   40.445    0.000 {built-in method builtins.getattr}
 79996390   39.995    0.000   52.367    0.000 /Users/eddie/dev/quippy/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tatsu/contexts.py:223(_pos)
246258630   39.345    0.000   39.345    0.000 /Users/eddie/dev/quippy/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tatsu/buffering.py:155(pos)
38860150/25041530   38.587    0.000  118.596    0.000 /Users/eddie/dev/quippy/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tatsu/objectmodel.py:108(__cn)
 95427954   38.319    0.000   38.319    0.000 {built-in method builtins.min}
15701720/80   38.148    0.000 3249.974   40.625 /Users/eddie/dev/quippy/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tatsu/contexts.py:536(_recursive_call)
 32060560   37.741    0.000   45.157    0.000 /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.4_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py:59(__init__)
```

Even the largest contributor (`_eat_regex`) cannot explain the 50 minute run-time. I also cannot find how to optimize for speed in the tatsu documentation.

Some more insight may be gained by looking at the cumulative time spent in functions. I've sorted the profiling results by `cumtime`:

```
Tue Feb 27 13:35:58 2018    parser_profiling

         4787639497 function calls (4611051402 primitive calls) in 3255.157 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time
   List reduced from 326 to 30 due to restriction <30>

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000 3273.337 3273.337 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1    0.000    0.000 3273.337 3273.337 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.005    0.005 3273.337 3273.337 test_model.py:95(test_optimizer)
       80    0.002    0.000 3272.954   40.912 /Users/eddie/dev/quippy/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tatsu/contexts.py:182(parse)
15701720/80   31.630    0.000 3249.977   40.625 /Users/eddie/dev/quippy/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tatsu/contexts.py:47(wrapper)
15701720/80   63.262    0.000 3249.976   40.625 /Users/eddie/dev/quippy/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tatsu/contexts.py:501(_call)
15701720/80   38.148    0.000 3249.974   40.625 /Users/eddie/dev/quippy/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tatsu/contexts.py:536(_recursive_call)
15701720/80   88.741    0.000 3249.970   40.625 /Users/eddie/dev/quippy/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tatsu/contexts.py:561(_invoke_rule)
       80    0.001    0.000 3174.181   39.677 /Users/eddie/dev/quippy/_parser.py:82(_start_)
  380/240    0.034    0.000 3169.206   13.205 /Users/eddie/dev/quippy/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tatsu/contexts.py:762(_closure)
      220    0.000    0.000 3164.452   14.384 /Users/eddie/dev/quippy/_parser.py:87(block2)
      220    0.003    0.000 3087.977   14.036 /Users/eddie/dev/quippy/_parser.py:121(_subroutine_)
624800/800   15.209    0.000 3076.119    3.845 /Users/eddie/dev/quippy/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tatsu/contexts.py:746(_repeat)
      220    0.002    0.000 3024.411   13.747 /Users/eddie/dev/quippy/_parser.py:101(_circuit_)
2578040/1272030    7.935    0.000 2970.683    0.002 /Users/eddie/dev/quippy/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tatsu/contexts.py:732(_isolate)
  1875860    3.029    0.000 2839.993    0.002 /Users/eddie/dev/quippy/_parser.py:108(block2)
  1875860   11.120    0.000 2483.056    0.001 /Users/eddie/dev/quippy/_parser.py:217(_gate_)
  1875860   25.944    0.000 1793.816    0.001 /Users/eddie/dev/quippy/_parser.py:256(_qgate_)
 48867260   46.582    0.000  724.214    0.000 /Users/eddie/dev/quippy/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tatsu/contexts.py:237(_next_token)
 45115140   69.378    0.000  671.723    0.000 /Users/eddie/dev/quippy/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tatsu/buffering.py:260(next_token)
 14443300   35.990    0.000  577.765    0.000 /Users/eddie/dev/quippy/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tatsu/contexts.py:598(_invoke_semantic_rule)
49442230/22727050   22.427    0.000  575.361    0.000 {built-in method builtins.next}
 18626000   41.821    0.000  545.252    0.000 /Users/eddie/dev/quippy/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tatsu/contexts.py:666(_option)
 48128890   19.695    0.000  497.263    0.000 /Users/eddie/dev/quippy/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tatsu/buffering.py:249(eat_whitespace)
32060560/13779580   12.309    0.000  493.588    0.000 /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.4_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py:79(__enter__)
144386670  129.008    0.000  491.328    0.000 /Users/eddie/dev/quippy/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tatsu/buffering.py:245(_eat_regex)
 14443300   34.625    0.000  460.941    0.000 /Users/eddie/dev/quippy/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tatsu/semantics.py:76(_default)
 18626000   61.979    0.000  454.538    0.000 /Users/eddie/dev/quippy/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tatsu/contexts.py:644(_try)
 17463860   36.024    0.000  415.958    0.000 /Users/eddie/dev/quippy/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tatsu/contexts.py:606(_token)
  4018330   18.630    0.000  410.825    0.000 /Users/eddie/dev/quippy/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tatsu/objectmodel.py:19(__init__)
```

We can see that quite some time is spent in choosing which gate is being performed (it is a large *choice* statement after all). A lot of time is also spent in `qgate` which is not surprising since these nodes are dominant in the code.

What are possible optimizations I can add to the grammar or parsing so that it can parse these files more quickly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be the `@@whitespace` definition, because it matches the empty string.

You could try:

```
@@whitespace :: /[^\S\n]+/
```

If that works, and the documentation misled you to use a normal closure for whitespace, please post an issue to the [issue base](https://github.com/neogeny/tatsu/issues)

Comment: That is good point! Parsing time is cut in approximately half to around 15 seconds for medium-sized files (38k LOC). Still fairly slow.

Comment: The next step should be to run a parse with tracing enabled to have a look at where the parser is actually spending its time. Odd recursions will show up there. (and please upvote/accept the answer as you see fit)